# Merge / Combine Two Active Record Results (has_and_belongs_to_many and belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I think this is perhaps straight forward but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a `Model` that has the following associations:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :locations, join_table: :model_locations
belongs_to :location_from, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "location_from_id"
belongs_to :location_to, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "location_to_id"
```

So `model.locations` can return 0, 1 or multiple records and `model.location_from` and `model.location_to` always present and single records.

What I am looking for is a combined result of all of these.  I know there is a convoluted SQL query to do this but it would be nice to have a simple Active Record statement.  I have looked at `merge()` and `<<` but none of these seem to work.

For side reference the SQL out put from the `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
  Location Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "model_locations" ON "locations"."id" = "model_locations"."location_id" WHERE "model_locations"."model_id" = $1  [["model_id", 17]]
```

The preferred answer is via Active Record but a raw SQL will do the trick too.

**UPDATE**

Progress added to an answer below - will still accept answers that compliment my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am half way there (sort of).  I added an answer here as to not make the question too long.

Here is my data:

```
irb(main):169:0> Location.find_by_sql('SELECT "model_locations".* FROM "model_locations"')
  Location Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "model_locations".* FROM "model_locations"
+----+---------------------+-------------+
| id |            model_id | location_id |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
|    | 17                  | 50          |
|    | 17                  | 51          |
|    | 10                  | 24          |
|    | 19                  | 11          |
|    | 19                  | 5           |
|    | 19                  | 51          |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
6 rows in set

irb(main):174:0> Model.select(:id, :location_from_id, :location_to_id)
  Model Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "models"."id", "models"."location_from_id", "models"."location_to_id" FROM "models"
+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | location_from_id | location_to_id |
+----+------------------+----------------+
| 17 | 1                | 5              |
| 18 | 50               | 24             |
| 10 | 3                | 8              |
| 1  | 50               | 11             |
| 19 | 1                | 5              |
| 20 | 1                | 11             |
| 21 | 11               | 5              |
+----+------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set
```

So for example:

```
Model 17 has Locations 50, 51 AND 1 ,5 
Location 11 has Models 19, 1 AND 20, 21
```

So I can find the Model Locations:

```
'SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" LEFT JOIN "model_locations" ON "locations"."id" = "model_locations"."location_id" WHERE "model_locations"."model_id" = 17 OR "locations"."id" IN (1,5)'
```

This works great - I get my 4 locations however I can't get the reverse to work:

```
'SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE "models"."location_from_id" = 11 OR "models"."location_to_id" = 11 INNER JOIN "model_locations" ON "model_locations"."model_id" = "models"."id" WHERE "models_locations"."location_id" = 11'
```

This fails at the INNER JOIN:

`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"`